# Android file not found exception when trying to upload file via FTP

Tags: java, android, ftp

I'm trying to upload a text file to a server via FTP. The text file is in data/data/my package/files (I have checked in the DDMS). I am getting a filenotfoundexception in LogCat.

Here's my code:

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
     FileInputStream fis = null;

   try {
     client.connect("82.163.99.80");
     client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
     client.login("user", "password");

     //
     // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
     //
     String filename = "sdcardstats.txt";
     fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

     //
     // Store file to server
     //
     client.storeFile(filename, fis);
     client.logout();
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
     try {
         if (fis != null) {
             fis.close();
         }
         client.disconnect();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     }
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You have not given the exact path to your file.

Comment: Assuming you're getting the exception on the like where you define the `FileInputStream`, it's not an FTP problem at all. If it's happening during the transfer, it depends on the FTP client you're using. I suspect it's the former. @ChintanRaghwani is right that you should be specifying absolute paths to files.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
```

... requires a path, not a file name.

Try instead:

```
fis = openFileInput(filename);
```

... which takes a file name and tries to open it in your application's private file storage area.  For more information, see the Android Developers Guide for Data Storage: [Internal Files](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), and [FileInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream%28java.lang.String%29) and [openFileInput](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Props to Chintan and Basic for the idea, but I take credit for looking up the references.  :-)